# [roslibjs,rosbridgesuite] How to get data back from the robot in turtleSim

Tags: turtlebot, turtlesim, rosbridge, rosbridge-suite, roslib

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to the roslibjs documentation, we should be able to get the data back from the robot by using a listener:

```
// Publish the Topic
var cmdVel = new ROSLIB.Topic({
    ros: ros,
    name: '/turtle1/cmd_vel',
    messageType: 'geometry_msgs/Twist'
});

// Subscribe to the Topic
var listener = new ROSLIB.Topic({
    ros: ros,
    name: '/listener',
    messageType: 'std_msgs/String'
});

listener.subscribe(function (message) {
    console.log("Recieved Message on: " + listener.name + ": " + message.data);
});
```

However, when I tried to use this, there was a compilation error that said `property 'data does not exist on type 'message'`.

I really need to get the turtle-robot data back to my web browser, any help with this matter would be highly appreciated.

Many thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/248347/%5Broslibjs,rosbridgesuite%5D-how-to-get-data-back-from-the-robot-in-turtlesim/) by [nerdyTurtle](https://answers.ros.org/users/28562/nerdyturtle/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2016-11-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-11-18**:
Could you please use the *Preformatted Text* button next time when copy-pasting console text, source code, etc? It's the one with `101010` on it. That will make things much easier to read.

Thanks.

**Comment by [nerdyTurtle](https://answers.ros.org/users/28562/nerdyturtle/) on 2016-11-28**:
@gvdhoorn will do!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was using Typescript, so I had to do add the following to the Typings file:

```
data:{
    ros: Ros,
    name: string,
    serviceType: string
}
```

---

Originally posted by [nerdyTurtle](https://answers.ros.org/users/28562/nerdyturtle/) with karma: 18 on 2016-11-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0